# error C4995: 'DwmEnableComposition': name was marked as #pragma deprecated in Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64, deprecated, aero

I am running a simple code to disable aero programmatically as mentioned here. Here is my MCVE:

```
// DisableAero.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <dwmapi.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    int i;
    // Disable DWM Composition 
    hr = DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        printf_s("AeroDisabled");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However when I build the code, it throws an error that

> error C4995: 'DwmEnableComposition': name was marked as #pragma
>   deprecated

I understand that this function has been deprecated as of Windows 8. But I am running this code on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Then why is visual studio throwing this error?

**UPDATE**

I checked inside the Properties in C++->General->Treat Warnings as errors and it is selected No (/WX-) 
Even then it is throwing this error. Do I need to change the setting in some other place as well? Attaching the screenshot of the properties window:

[image: properties window]

**UPDATE 2**
I changed the warning level to 'turn off all warnings (/W0) Even then I am getting the same error.
Attaching the screenshot of properties window:

[image: properties window]

**UPDATE 3**
When I go to Properties->C/C++->Advanced-> Disable Specific warnings I am supposed to  And enter text.
Attaching screenshots for reference:
[image: disable specific warnings]
[image: Disable specific warnings -> <Edit..>]

**UPDATE 4**

This is the complete code present in **targetver.h**

```
#pragma once

// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.

// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

And this is **stdafx.h**

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>



// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

Where do I change the target version setting to?

I tried changing targetver.h include to

```
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
```

It is still giving the same error

**UPDATE 5**

This is the complete code inside **sdkddkver.h**

```
/*

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Module Name:

    sdkddkver.h

Abstract:

    Master include file for versioning windows SDK/DDK.

*/

#ifndef _INC_SDKDDKVER
#define _INC_SDKDDKVER

#if (_MSC_VER >= 800)
#if (_MSC_VER >= 1200)
#pragma warning(push)
#endif
#pragma warning(disable:4001) /* nonstandard extension : single line comment */
#endif

#pragma once

//
// _WIN32_WINNT version constants
//
#define _WIN32_WINNT_NT4                    0x0400
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K                  0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP                  0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WS03                   0x0502
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN6                   0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA                  0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WS08                   0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_LONGHORN               0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7                   0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8                   0x0602
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE                0x0603

//
// _WIN32_IE_ version constants
//
#define _WIN32_IE_IE20                      0x0200
#define _WIN32_IE_IE30                      0x0300
#define _WIN32_IE_IE302                     0x0302
#define _WIN32_IE_IE40                      0x0400
#define _WIN32_IE_IE401                     0x0401
#define _WIN32_IE_IE50                      0x0500
#define _WIN32_IE_IE501                     0x0501
#define _WIN32_IE_IE55                      0x0550
#define _WIN32_IE_IE60                      0x0600
#define _WIN32_IE_IE60SP1                   0x0601
#define _WIN32_IE_IE60SP2                   0x0603
#define _WIN32_IE_IE70                      0x0700
#define _WIN32_IE_IE80                      0x0800
#define _WIN32_IE_IE90                      0x0900
#define _WIN32_IE_IE100                     0x0A00

//
// IE <-> OS version mapping
//
// NT4 supports IE versions 2.0 -> 6.0 SP1
#define _WIN32_IE_NT4                       _WIN32_IE_IE20
#define _WIN32_IE_NT4SP1                    _WIN32_IE_IE20
#define _WIN32_IE_NT4SP2                    _WIN32_IE_IE20
#define _WIN32_IE_NT4SP3                    _WIN32_IE_IE302
#define _WIN32_IE_NT4SP4                    _WIN32_IE_IE401
#define _WIN32_IE_NT4SP5                    _WIN32_IE_IE401
#define _WIN32_IE_NT4SP6                    _WIN32_IE_IE50
// Win98 supports IE versions 4.01 -> 6.0 SP1
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN98                     _WIN32_IE_IE401
// Win98SE supports IE versions 5.0 -> 6.0 SP1
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN98SE                   _WIN32_IE_IE50
// WinME supports IE versions 5.5 -> 6.0 SP1
#define _WIN32_IE_WINME                     _WIN32_IE_IE55
// Win2k supports IE versions 5.01 -> 6.0 SP1
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN2K                     _WIN32_IE_IE501
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN2KSP1                  _WIN32_IE_IE501
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN2KSP2                  _WIN32_IE_IE501
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN2KSP3                  _WIN32_IE_IE501
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN2KSP4                  _WIN32_IE_IE501
#define _WIN32_IE_XP                        _WIN32_IE_IE60
#define _WIN32_IE_XPSP1                     _WIN32_IE_IE60SP1
#define _WIN32_IE_XPSP2                     _WIN32_IE_IE60SP2
#define _WIN32_IE_WS03                      0x0602
#define _WIN32_IE_WS03SP1                   _WIN32_IE_IE60SP2
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN6                      _WIN32_IE_IE70
#define _WIN32_IE_LONGHORN                  _WIN32_IE_IE70
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN7                      _WIN32_IE_IE80
#define _WIN32_IE_WIN8                      _WIN32_IE_IE100
#define _WIN32_IE_WINBLUE                   _WIN32_IE_IE100


//
// NTDDI version constants
//
#define NTDDI_WIN2K                         0x05000000
#define NTDDI_WIN2KSP1                      0x05000100
#define NTDDI_WIN2KSP2                      0x05000200
#define NTDDI_WIN2KSP3                      0x05000300
#define NTDDI_WIN2KSP4                      0x05000400

#define NTDDI_WINXP                         0x05010000
#define NTDDI_WINXPSP1                      0x05010100
#define NTDDI_WINXPSP2                      0x05010200
#define NTDDI_WINXPSP3                      0x05010300
#define NTDDI_WINXPSP4                      0x05010400

#define NTDDI_WS03                          0x05020000
#define NTDDI_WS03SP1                       0x05020100
#define NTDDI_WS03SP2                       0x05020200
#define NTDDI_WS03SP3                       0x05020300
#define NTDDI_WS03SP4                       0x05020400

#define NTDDI_WIN6                          0x06000000
#define NTDDI_WIN6SP1                       0x06000100
#define NTDDI_WIN6SP2                       0x06000200
#define NTDDI_WIN6SP3                       0x06000300
#define NTDDI_WIN6SP4                       0x06000400

#define NTDDI_VISTA                         NTDDI_WIN6
#define NTDDI_VISTASP1                      NTDDI_WIN6SP1
#define NTDDI_VISTASP2                      NTDDI_WIN6SP2
#define NTDDI_VISTASP3                      NTDDI_WIN6SP3
#define NTDDI_VISTASP4                      NTDDI_WIN6SP4

#define NTDDI_LONGHORN  NTDDI_VISTA

#define NTDDI_WS08                          NTDDI_WIN6SP1
#define NTDDI_WS08SP2                       NTDDI_WIN6SP2
#define NTDDI_WS08SP3                       NTDDI_WIN6SP3
#define NTDDI_WS08SP4                       NTDDI_WIN6SP4

#define NTDDI_WIN7                          0x06010000
#define NTDDI_WIN8                          0x06020000
#define NTDDI_WINBLUE                       0x06030000


//
// masks for version macros
//
#define OSVERSION_MASK      0xFFFF0000
#define SPVERSION_MASK      0x0000FF00
#define SUBVERSION_MASK     0x000000FF


//
// macros to extract various version fields from the NTDDI version
//
#define OSVER(Version)  ((Version) & OSVERSION_MASK)
#define SPVER(Version)  (((Version) & SPVERSION_MASK) >> 8)
#define SUBVER(Version) (((Version) & SUBVERSION_MASK) )


#if defined(DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK)

// deprecate in 2k or later
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN2K)
#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_WIN2K DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK
#else
#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_WIN2K
#endif

// deprecate in XP or later
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINXP)
#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_WINXP DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK
#else
#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_WINXP
#endif

// deprecate in WS03 or later
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WS03)
#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_WIN2003 DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK
#else
#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_WIN2003
#endif

// deprecate in WIN6 or later
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN6)
#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_WIN6 DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK
#else
#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_WIN6
#endif

#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_LONGHORN DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK_WIN6

#endif // defined(DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK)


//
// if versions aren't already defined, default to most current
//

#define NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT2(ver)    ver##0000
#define NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT(ver)     NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT2(ver)

#if !defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && !defined(_CHICAGO_)
#define  _WIN32_WINNT   0x0603
#endif

#ifndef NTDDI_VERSION
#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
// set NTDDI_VERSION based on _WIN32_WINNT
#define NTDDI_VERSION   NTDDI_VERSION_FROM_WIN32_WINNT(_WIN32_WINNT)
#else
#define NTDDI_VERSION   0x06030000
#endif
#endif

#ifndef WINVER
#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
// set WINVER based on _WIN32_WINNT
#define WINVER          _WIN32_WINNT
#else
#define WINVER          0x0603
#endif
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_IE
#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
// set _WIN32_IE based on _WIN32_WINNT
#if (_WIN32_WINNT <= _WIN32_WINNT_NT4)
#define _WIN32_IE       _WIN32_IE_IE50
#elif (_WIN32_WINNT <= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K)
#define _WIN32_IE       _WIN32_IE_IE501
#elif (_WIN32_WINNT <= _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP)
#define _WIN32_IE       _WIN32_IE_IE60
#elif (_WIN32_WINNT <= _WIN32_WINNT_WS03)
#define _WIN32_IE       _WIN32_IE_WS03
#elif (_WIN32_WINNT <= _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA)
#define _WIN32_IE       _WIN32_IE_LONGHORN
#elif (_WIN32_WINNT <= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7)
#define _WIN32_IE       _WIN32_IE_WIN7
#elif (_WIN32_WINNT <= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
#define _WIN32_IE       _WIN32_IE_WIN8
#else
#define _WIN32_IE       0x0A00
#endif
#else
#define _WIN32_IE       0x0A00
#endif
#endif

//
// Sanity check for compatible versions
//
#if defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && !defined(MIDL_PASS) && !defined(RC_INVOKED)

#if (defined(WINVER) && (WINVER < 0x0400) && (_WIN32_WINNT > 0x0400))
#error WINVER setting conflicts with _WIN32_WINNT setting
#endif

#if (((OSVERSION_MASK & NTDDI_VERSION) == NTDDI_WIN2K) && (_WIN32_WINNT != _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K))
#error NTDDI_VERSION setting conflicts with _WIN32_WINNT setting
#endif

#if (((OSVERSION_MASK & NTDDI_VERSION) == NTDDI_WINXP) && (_WIN32_WINNT != _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP))
#error NTDDI_VERSION setting conflicts with _WIN32_WINNT setting
#endif

#if (((OSVERSION_MASK & NTDDI_VERSION) == NTDDI_WS03) && (_WIN32_WINNT != _WIN32_WINNT_WS03))
#error NTDDI_VERSION setting conflicts with _WIN32_WINNT setting
#endif

#if (((OSVERSION_MASK & NTDDI_VERSION) == NTDDI_VISTA) && (_WIN32_WINNT != _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA))
#error NTDDI_VERSION setting conflicts with _WIN32_WINNT setting
#endif

#if ((_WIN32_WINNT < _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K) && (_WIN32_IE > _WIN32_IE_IE60SP1))
#error _WIN32_WINNT settings conflicts with _WIN32_IE setting
#endif

#endif  // defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && !defined(MIDL_PASS) && !defined(_WINRESRC_)

#if (_MSC_VER >= 800)
#if (_MSC_VER >= 1200)
#pragma warning(pop)
#else
#pragma warning(default:4001) /* nonstandard extension : single line comment */
#endif
#endif

#endif  /* !_INC_SDKDDKVER */
```

Comment: That should be a warning, not an error... Maybe you enabled "treat warnings as errors"?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I checked inside Properties->C/C++->General->Treat Warnings as errors and it has been selected No. Even then I am getting this error! Am I supposed to change the properties at some other place as well?

Comment: See if that warning is set to error level in Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Specific Warnings.

Comment: @AlanStokes The error level in the Disable Specific Warnings is blank. And we need to enter text on pressing the <Edit..> Tab. What do I set it to?

Comment: If doesn't matter on what OS you are building the code. What matters is the target OS that is set with  `WINVER` (or `_WIN32_WINNT`) macros. This could be either on `stdafx.h` or `targetver.h` headers or elsewhere, depending on how your project was set.

Comment: @MariusBancila I updated my question with the code present in `stdafx.h` and `targetver.h` What changes do I make and where to set the right target OS?

Comment: OK, but what SDK do you have installed? What is the value of `WINVER` in `SDKDDKVer.h`?

Comment: @MariusBancila it is `#define WINVER          _WIN32_WINNT` Should I change it? What should I change it to?

Comment: `#define WINVER 0x0603` and that is windows 8.1. Change that in your `targetver.h` to `#define WINVER 0x0601` to indicate Windows 7.

Comment: I added `#define WINVER 0x0601` but still I am getting the same error. I then also changed the _sdkddkver.h_ definitions of WINVER to `#ifndef WINVER
#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
// set WINVER based on _WIN32_WINNT
#define WINVER          0x0601
#else
#define WINVER          0x0601
#endif
#endif
`
But still I am getting the same error.